# jQuery each function does not apply style

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have two jQuery functions that loop through several elements any apply style to 'em. I have a `select` and want to hide all divs in a specific parent element. After that, the selected element should be visible again.

The hiding function (unsung `each()`) does work. But the second one, that is used to display them, does not. I have tried two approaches, one using `each()`, the second one using `css()`. Both do not work. When I log the elements inside the both `each()` functions, they return the exact same elements.

What is missing here? Why do the styles not apply?!

```
function selectTab(sender) {
    jQuery(sender).parent().find('.tab').each(function() {
        this.style.display = 'none';
    });

    // these two don't work
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(sender).val()).each(function() {
        this.style.display = 'block';
    });
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(sender).val()).css({display: 'block'});
```

Comment: use $(this) instead of this

Comment: can you provide a fiddle?

Comment: What is `this` in the non-working ones? If the non-working lines are selecting by element id why do they need the `.each()` loop? Do you have multiple elements with the same id?

Comment: All lines are fired from the same function, so `this` is always the same. I updated my code. I use the `.each()` loop, because it's likely I'll change `id` to `class` in the future. And so I don't have to edit the code again (except the selector)

Comment: @SomnathKharat: No. When using `.style.display`, it's plain old JavaScript, not jQuery. And the first block of code does work.

Comment: jQuery('#' + jQuery(sender).val()) here you are using ID and we can not repeat same ID, that means we can't use .each on it

Comment: `jQuery('#' + jQuery(sender).val())` does return an element set, like every other jQuery function does. This, in fact, means that we `CAN` use `.eacht()` on it. Simple test: http://jsfiddle.net/julian_weinert/96BL2/

Comment: ID is unique identifier, we can select it with simple select statement  and each is use to select set of element , therefore why we use each on ID

Comment: Read the third and fourth comment. There you'll find the answer. You are right, it's not worth it. But it **IS** possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Forget about it. In a fiddle it's working great.

It has something to do with the rest of the `DOM`, this code is embedded in a WordPress widget. I won't think I'll ever solve this issue, it seems like WordPress is breaking jQuery entirely, some other jQuery plugins don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).parent().find('.tab').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display', 'none');
});


// these two don't work
jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).each(function() {
   $(this).css('display', 'block');
});
jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).css('display', 'block');
```

try this way

Comment: It's logical redundant to my original code... And it does not work. It's the same as before. The hiding part works, the other one does not.

Comment: @Julian: when you say its doesnt work, you mean  the displays of the tabs back again  right ?

Comment: @Julian: to solve your issue, i would need the respective dom structure ,atleast from the point where the `selectTab` event  is triggered

Comment: Forget about it. In a fiddle it's working great. It has something to do with the rest of the `DOM`, this code is embedded in a WordPress widget. I won't think I'll ever solve this issue, it seems like WordPress is breaking jQuery entirely, some other jQuery plugins don't work either.

Answer (score 0):

TRy

```
jQuery(this).parent().find('.tab').each(function() {
    jQuery(this).css('display','none');
});

// these two don't work
    jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).each(function() {

  jQuery(this).css('display','block');
});
jQuery('#' + jQuery(this).val()).css({display: 'block'});
```

**OR**

```
$(this).parent().find('.tab').each(function() {
    $(this).css('display','none');
});

// these two don't work
    $('#' + $(this).val()).each(function() {

  $(this).css('display','block');
});
$('#' + $(this).val()).css({display: 'block'});
```

Comment: It's logical redundant to my original code... And it does not work. It's the same as before. The hiding part works, the other one does not.